# How to save an array to two class methods?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have two classes:

```
void Dice::toss()
{
    int dices[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        dices[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;
    }

}

int Dice::getValue()
{
    return dices[i] ?
}
```

How can I save the value from dices[i] in first class to the other?

Comment: *How can I save the value from dices[i] in first class to the other?* - Do you mean *method* instead of *class*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **one** class with (at least) **two** methods.

It looks like you want `dices` to be a class member, and that way both methods can see it.

Your class definition would be:

```
class Dice {
    int dices[SIZE];
    void toss();
    int getValue();
};
```

And then take the declaration of `dices[SIZE]` out of `toss`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make `dices` a member of the `Dice` class:

```
class Dice{
    int dices[SIZE];
    void toss();
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `dices` into a member of the class instead of a local variable:

Header:

```
class Dice
{
private:
    int dices[SIZE];

public:
    void toss();
    int getValue(int i);
    // etc...
}
```

Implementation:

```
void Dice::toss()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        dices[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;
    }
}

int Dice::getValue(int i)
{
    return dices[i];
}
```